# How can I stop repeating code when I do for loops to count different criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 20 worksheets, with the names "WorksheetNumber1", "WorksheetNumber2", "WorksheetNumber3", "WorksheetNumber4", ..., "WorksheetNumber20".

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Sub()
    Dim Workbook1 As Workbok
    Dim count As Long

    count = 0
    For i = 1 To 20
        Select Case IsEmpty(Workbook1.Worksheets("WorksheetNumber" & i).Cells(1,1))
            Case True
                count = count + 1
        End Select
    Next i
    MsgBox(count)

    count = 0
    For i = 1 To 20
        Select Case Application.CountA(Workbook1.Worksheets("WorksheetNumber" & i).Range("$C$3:$E$5"))>0
            Case True
                count = count + 1
        End Select
    Next i
    MsgBox(count)

End Sub
```

I have many more of these loops repeated, except only the criteria is different. So, as you can see, the structure of the code is for each of the loops is the same, but the Select Case criteria is changed. How can I shorten my very long code?

I've tried to create a function that makes the Select Case criteria variable, but it doesn't quite seem to work because the criteria is evaluated before it goes into the function.

Here is what I have:

```
Function f_1(Criteria As Variant, Workbook1) As Long
    f_1 = 0
    For i = 1 To 20
        Select Case Criteria
            Case True
                f_1 = Application.Sum(f_1, 1)
        End Select
    Next i
End Function
```

And here is the subroutine that attempts to call the function:

```
Sub(Workbook1 As Workbook)
    Dim count As Long

    'example A
    count = f_1(IsEmpty(Workbook1.Worksheets("WorksheetNumber" & i).Cells(1,1)), Workbook1)
    MsgBox(count)

    'example B
    count = f_1(Application.CountA(Workbook1.Worksheets("WorksheetNumber" & i).Range("$C$3:$E$5"))>0, Workbook1)
    MsgBox(count)
End Sub
```

What's happening is that the statement

```
IsEmpty(Workbook1.Worksheets("WorksheetNumber" & i).Cells(1,1))
```

and the statement

```
Application.CountA(Workbook1.Worksheets("WorksheetNumber" & i).Range("$C$3:$E$5"))>0
```

is being evaluated before it gets sent into the function, so, depending on what **i** is, one worksheet gets evaluated 20 times (if **i** happens to be between 1 and 20, inclusive), or the subscript is out of range (if **i** is not between 1 and 20, inclusive).

I've asked around for help, and someone suggested creating objects; I've googled this a bit, but I'm not entirely sure how that would help me, so if anyone can help me specify my search terms more, that'd be awesome too!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you have only one `case` in each of your `select`?

Comment: I don't quite understand why that is an issue... Are you suggesting I use an If Then that only takes one line?

Comment: It's not an issue. I was wondering why you couldn't roll all your loops into one but looking below you need a unique counter for each case so you can't without lots of counters as you explained.

Answer (score 0):

Where I see repetition is the loop structure. I would use code like this with one-liner conditionals if it is not important which condition increases the counter variable. You can add as many conditions you want and code keep relatively flat.
By the way it´s good to use the "Option explicit". In your first line Workbook has the typo "Workbok"

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim workbook1 As Workbook
Set workbook1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Long, count As Long
For i = 1 To Worksheets.count
    If IsEmpty(workbook1.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Cells(1, 1)) Then count = count + 1
    If Application.CountA(workbook1.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Range("$C$3:$E$5")) > 0 Then count = count + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
Instead of using different count variables as you commented I would prefer to have all condition counters bundled in one place. This can be done with an array or a dictionary.

Using an array:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UseOfArray()
Dim workbook1 As Workbook
Set workbook1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Long
Dim conditions_in_array(1 To 20) As Long

For i = 1 To Worksheets.count
    If IsEmpty(workbook1.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Cells(1, 1)) Then conditions_in_array(1) = conditions_in_array(1) + 1
    If workbook1.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color = 16777215 Then conditions_in_array(2) = conditions_in_array(2) + 1
Next i
Debug.Print "conditions_in_array(1): "; conditions_in_array(1); vbNewLine; "conditions_in_array(2): "; conditions_in_array(2)

End Sub
```

Using a dictionary (I would prefer this approach as with more conditions it is easier to debug):

```
Sub UseOfDictionary()
Dim i As Long
Dim workbook1 As Workbook
Set workbook1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim conditions_in_dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set conditions_in_dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
conditions_in_dict("cell_IsEmpty") = 0
conditions_in_dict("cell_uncolored") = 0
'here you can enter more keys as conditions as above

For i = 1 To Worksheets.count
    If IsEmpty(workbook1.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Cells(1, 1)) Then conditions_in_dict("cell_IsEmpty") = conditions_in_dict("cell_IsEmpty") + 1
    If workbook1.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color = 16777215 Then conditions_in_dict("cell_uncolored") = conditions_in_dict("cell_uncolored") + 1
Next i
Debug.Print "conditions_in_dict(""cell_IsEmpty""): "; conditions_in_dict("cell_IsEmpty"); vbNewLine; _
"conditions_in_dict(""cell_uncolored""): "; conditions_in_dict("cell_uncolored")

End Sub
```

Comment: I like cekar’s approach, do you need different counters for each condition?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But yes, unfortunately, I do need different counters for each condition. I suppose I could just have a unique counter variable for each condition though? It wouldn't be ideal, but, I do suppose that could work....